# Will i18next affect SEO? What about screen readers?

Tags: seo, javascript, language

I'm considering using [i18next](http://i18next.com/) for translating text. But then it suddenly struck me; If labels / text is retrieved through javascript, won't that affect SEO?

And what about screen readers for visual impaired users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge Googlebot reads javascript.
Use the appropriate tags in every language version as described in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
```

`<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/bg" hreflang="bg" />`
`<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en" />`

Comment: And so does screen readers: http://a11yproject.com/posts/myth-screen-readers-dont-use-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge with a very close Blind friend who uses a Mac for his screen reader, the iOS and OS X is very good at reading text on a website. As for images, you can forget it. The program will tell him there is an image on it, but it can not read text or what the image is about.

Also, he and a lot of people scrap a webpage for the reading of text only who is blind.

Comment: My question though, was if I used javascripts for labels, will it affect screen readers?. To answer myself, I just found this http://a11yproject.com/posts/myth-screen-readers-dont-use-javascript/ :)